# Get a 1:1 match between records, based on two fields, then group them together?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

```
Date    Client  Amount | table x
123     abc     123
456     abc     987
234     xyz     567


Date    Client  Amount | table y
123     abc     234
921     lka     981
234     xyz     123
```

In my query, I want to display:

```
123     abc     123     | (from x)
123     abc     234     | (from y)
234     xyz     567     | x
234     xyz     123     | y
```

Leaving out all records without a "partner."  Is this possible in TSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select DISTINCT
           case when c='x' then x.date else y.date end date,
           case when c='x' then x.client else y.client end client,
           case when c='x' then x.amount else y.amount end amount,
           c from_
      from tablex x
      join tabley y on x.date=y.date and x.client=y.client
cross join (select 'x' union all select 'y') z(c)
  order by date, client, from_;
```

An alternative to the accepted solution.

Note that where you have multiple matches from either/both tables, all the results from 'x' will be listed before the matches from 'y'. e.g.

```
create table tablex (Date int, Client char(3), Amount int);
insert tablex select
    123     ,'abc',     123 union all select
    456     ,'abc',     987 union all select
    123     ,'abc',     919 union all select
    234     ,'xyz',     567;
create table tabley (Date int, Client char(3), Amount int);
insert tabley select
    123     ,'abc',     234 union all select
    123     ,'abc',     867 union all select
    921     ,'lka',     981 union all select
    234     ,'xyz',     123;

**Results**

date        client amount      from_
----------- ------ ----------- -----
123         abc    123         x
123         abc    919         x
123         abc    234         y
123         abc    867         y
234         xyz    567         x
234         xyz    123         y
```

Comment: Your solution is less intuitive but more versatile.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.[Date] , a.[Client] , a.[Amount], 'X' [table]
FROM   tableX a INNER JOIN tableY b 
          ON a.[DATE] = b.[DATE] AND
             a.[Client] = b.[Client]
UNION
SELECT a.[Date] , a.[Client] , a.[Amount], 'Y' [table]
FROM   tableY a INNER JOIN tableX b 
          ON a.[DATE] = b.[DATE] AND
             a.[Client] = b.[Client]
ORDER BY [DATE], [Table]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/079ba/7)